# Cannot compile C++11 code via Makefile

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, avr, compile, build

I am building my Arduino project with a makefile:

```
BOARD_TAG = uno
ARDUINO_PORT = /dev/ttyACM0
USER_LIB_PATH = /home/prakhar/dev/alfred/arduino/libraries
CPPFLAGS=-x c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -DUNIX_ENVIRONMENT -DHAVE_NAMESPACES -DHAVE_STD
include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk
```

I keep getting this error:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

I googled and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674597/cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-std-c11-with-g) says that I need to update g++/gcc. I already have the newset versions:

```
prakhar@sim74stic ~ $ avr-g++ --version
avr-g++ (GCC) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

prakhar@sim74stic ~ $ avr-gcc --version
avr-gcc (GCC) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

prakhar@sim74stic ~ $ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I installed `arduino` from the `AUR` (packages `aur/arduino 1:1.0.6-1` and `aur/arduino-mk 1.3.4-2`).
Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check out the first few comments here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/arduino/  It may help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I C++11 to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I turns out, the `avr-gcc (GCC) 4.9.1` goodies weren't being used at all! The arduino package was using a decrepit version of gcc,

```
prakhar@sim74stic ~ $ /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ --version
avr-g++ (GCC) 4.3.2
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

prakhar@sim74stic ~ $ /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc --version
avr-gcc (GCC) 4.3.2
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**All I had to do was specify**:

```
AVR_TOOLS_DIR = /usr
```

to exexute with `-std=c++11` flag (I also had to add an `-fpermissive` flag to compile `C` with `g++`).